# How to Start/Stop Tomcat for normal user except root in Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, root, start-stop-daemon

I just install Tomcat6 in my Linux CentOS and I just want user to Start/Stop Tomcat without permission denied, there only root have no permission to do so. 
Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the root account?  If so, you could enable the ability to use sudo.  If not, you'll probably be better off using a local (i.e. non-system-wide) installation of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a rule in `visudo`. Something like;

```
Cmnd_Alias     CUSTOM_CMD = /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh, /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

myuser        ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:CUSTOM_CMD
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to [use `jsvc`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon).